# Tools for JPEG optimization?

Tags: optimization, jpeg

Do you know of any tools (preferrably command-line) to automatically and losslessly optimize JPEGs that I could integrate into our build environment? For PNGs I'm currently using [PNGOUT](http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm), and it generally saves around 40% bandwidth/image size.

At the very least, I would like a tool that can strip metadata from the JPGs - I noticed a strange case where I tried to make thumbnail from a photograph, and couldn't get it smaller than 34 kB. After investigating more, I found that the EXIF data was still part of the image, and the thumbnail was 3 kB after removing the metadata.

And beyond that - is it possible to further optimize JPGs losslessly? The PNG optimizer tries different compression strategies, random initialization of the Huffmann encoding etc.

I am aware that most savings come from the JPEG quality parameter, and that it's a rather subjective measure. I'm only looking for a tool that can be run as a build step and that losslessly squeezes a few bytes from the images.

Comment: You're saying that there was about 10KB worth of EXIF in an optimized JPG before EXIF was removed?!?!?! I wonder what's in it!

Comment: It was the whole EXIF block from a digital camera, including every little detail about this photograph (exposure, shutter time, etc...)

Comment: @netrox chris166 Those details don't take much space, what takes a lot of space is previews (binary data).

Comment: Two interesting comparison articles, that list utilities listed below: [Comparison of JPEG Lossless Compression Tools, June 2014](https://blarg.co.uk/blog/comparison-of-jpeg-lossless-compression-tools); [JPEG optimization tools benchmark, Feb 2013](http://blog.jsdelivr.com/2013/02/jpeg-optimization-tools-benchmark.html).

Comment: @Ariel: ICC profile also tends to take a large space. I have seen over 500KB of ICC profile binary data.

Comment: What is wrong with you StackOverflow? A question with 110 votes gets closed?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I use libjpeg for lossless operations. It contains a command-line tool [**jpegtran**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpegtran) that can do all you want. With the commandline option `-copy none` all the metadata is stripped, and `-optimize` does a lossless optimization of the Huffmann compression. You can also convert the images to progressive mode with `-progressive`, but that might cause compatibility problems (does anyone know more about that?)

Comment: Wow, that sounds promising. If anyone is interested, the download for Windows is at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jpeg.htm

Comment: I'm going for this one. It reduces my background image from 62 kB to 49 kB in progressive mode. Another image (27 kB) was reduced to 23 kB. That's 15-20% savings without loss in quality!

Comment: progressive works fine in basically everything, the only drawback is it uses more CPU to decode (not enough extra to matter).

Comment: the progressive can often be bigger than baseline for files less than 9k

Comment: Progressive needs a lot more memory to decode. Regular jpegs can be streamed: you only need to decode in small sections. To decode a progressive jpg you need to hold the entire decompressed image in memory at once.

Comment: Older versions of adoble flash couldn't load progressive JPEGs. We are talking version 6 and older, so that shouldn't be a concern by now.

Comment: This python script uses libjpeg, should do the trick if you want to run it in a batch: https://github.com/joedicastro/img4web

Comment: @CollinAnderson definitely agree. Every format has it's use and purpose. Progressive Jpeg is not a begin all end all format and should not be used for everything, as a desktop background it is near useless. For webdesign however it has many. rule of thumb: small images with minimal colour complexity such as used for buttons, banners "PNG/PNG-8" ftw. for small images ie (less than 10-15kb) GIF/PNG/JPG, for larger images with colour complexity such as photo's and such Progressive Jpeg especially if you aren't using a CDN for content.

Comment: psst @NiloVelez, flash is dead for the web and should stay that way, viva la HTML5,JS and SVG.  the security issues, lack of mobile support, lack of responsiveness not providing anything that cannot be done better than standard html,css and js. more effort than progress... valid point though for the flashlovers ...

Comment: Note that Rockbox (for MP3 players/hacked ipods) doesn't support progressive JPEGs either.

Answer (score 72):

I wrote a [GUI for all image optimization tools I could find](https://imageoptim.com/), including [MozJPEG](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) and `jpegoptim` that optimize Huffman tables, progressive scans, and (optionally) remove invisible metadata.

[image: ImageOptim smushing it]

If you don't have a Mac, I also have a basic [web interface](https://imageoptim.com/mozjpeg) that works on any platform.

Comment: Excellent! You, sir, need a Flattr button. Or join Gittip.

Comment: ImageOptim and ImageAlpha are great!

Comment: Great tool - minor suggestion. Why restrict JPEGoptim to 80% quality - large background images often you'd want to go to 60% or even lower.

thx

Comment: why remove EXIF data? :/

Comment: @AdrienBe 1. Privacy. You may not want everyone on the net know your GPS location. 2. because in files saved from Photoshop there can be **megabytes** of XML garbage embedded in the files.

Comment: @Kornel right. That makes sense. Didn't know Photoshop did that. Should I be surprised (*shaking my head*)

Answer (score 12):

A new service called [JPEGmini](http://www.jpegmini.com/main/home) produces incredible results. <s>A shame that it's online only.</s> **Edit**: It's available for Windows and Mac now

Comment: We now have a Mac app available  (disclosure: I'm on the development team)

Comment: I don't know if you're the author or not, but that app is misleading users. If you run [jpegquality.c](http://www.hackerfactor.com/src/jpegquality.c) on their "mini" images to detect the compression amount, and then compress the originals with imagemagick with the same quality => you get the same results, same JPEG artifacts in both images. Imagemagick may be open-source, but that doesn't make it ok to use it and then claim you developed a new compression technology

Comment: @onetrickpony: I'm not affiliated with them in any way.

Comment: @niceass How do you know that JPEGmini is using ImageMagick code ? Knowing the quality factor is the same as output from IM is not proof. My guess is that they recompress the image at reducing quality factors perhaps with a little bit of filtering and they use some quality metric to decide when to stop.

Comment: I ran the latest JPEGmini on an image I had previously exported from ImageMagick and it was reported that JPEGmini had already been run on it - which I don't remember doing. Running jpegtran -optimize -copy none on the same image reduced size by 12 KB.

Answer (score 12):

**[WINDOWS ONLY]**

RIOT(Radical Image Optimization Tool)
This is the greatest image optimization tool I have found!

http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/

You can easily get a 10MB image down to 800KB through sub-sampling.
It supports PNG, GIF, and JPEG.
It even integrates into context menus so you can send pictures straight there.
Allows you to rotate, re-size, compress to specified KB's, and more. Also has plugins for GIMP and IrfanView and other things.

There is also a DLL available if you want to incorporate it into your own programs or java script / c++ program.

Another alternative is http://pnggauntlet.com/ PNGGAUNTLET takes forever but it does a pretty good job.

**[WINDOWS ONLY]**

Comment: **Warning:** RIOT looks good but it installs TuneUp and shit without asking you,.. I'd classify this as Malware.

Comment: @DanFromGermany is right. See reviews here: http://download.cnet.com/RIOT/3000-12511_4-10911908.html#summaryList

Comment: It never did until recently.

Comment: Malware alert! Chrome download manager warns RIOT is malware

Comment: FYI: There is a portable .zip file for RIOT that contains no malware or installers of any kind. Just scroll down on their downloads page. http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/download/

Comment: oh crap I just downloaded RIOT. i'm uninstalling it right now! O_O

Answer (score 10):

Tried a number of the suggestions above - I personally was after lossless compression.

My sample image had an original size of 67,737 bytes.

Using kraken.io, it went down to 64,718
Using jpegtran, it went down to 64,718
Using yahoo smush-it, it went down to 61,746
Using imagemagick (-strip), it went down to 65,312

The smush.py option looks promising, but the installation was too complex for me to do quickly

jpegrescan looks promising too, but seems to be unix and I'm using windows

jpegmini is NOT lossless, but I can't tell the difference (down to 22,172)

plinth's Altrasoft jpegstripper app does not work on my windows 7

jpegoptim is not windows - no good for me

Riot (keeping quality at 100%) got it down to 63,416 and with chroma subsampling set to high, it got it down to 61,912 - I don't know if that is lossless or not though, and I think it looks lighter than the original.

So my verdict is yahoo smushit if it must be lossless

Comment: jpegrescan works on Windows if you're stubborn. It shaves off size like magic (5-15% with no loss in quality), which is amazing, because it's just re-ordering the progressive scan ordering AFAIK (you might notice the same in other programs, files sometimes get marginally smaller in Photoshop if you choose different number of scans, for no apparent reason). Also, it was made by one of the guys that made x264, he's such a prodigy in the field of compression.

Answer (score 9):

I would try Imagemagick. It has tons of command line options, its free and have a nice license.
http://www.imagemagick.org

There seems to be an option called Strip that may help you:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know ImageMagick could do that.

Answer (score 7):

ImageOptim is really slick. The command line option posted by the author will populate the GUI and show progress. I used jpegtran for optimizing and converting to progressive, then ImageOptim for further progressive optimizations and for other file types.

Reuse of script code also found in this forum (all files replaced in place):

## jpegtran

```sh
for file in $(find $DIR -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.jpeg" -or -name "*.JPG" \)); do
    echo found $file for optimizing...
    jpegtran -copy comments -optimize -progressive -outfile $file $file
done
```

## ImageOptim

```sh
for file in $(find $DIR -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.png" -or -name "*.gif" \)); do
do
    echo found $file for optimizing...
    open -a ImageOptim.app $file
done
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone's looking, I've written an offline version of Yahoo's Smush.it. It will losslessly optimise pngs, jpgs and gifs (animated and static):

http://github.com/thebeansgroup/smush.py

Comment: It works fine but there is a problem with png compression :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jpegoptim](http://www.kokkonen.net/tjko/projects.html) which will losslessly optimize jpeg files by default. The `--strip-all` option strips all extra embedded info. You can also specify a lossy mode with the `--max` switch which is useful when you have images saved with a very high quality setting, which is not necessary for eg. web content.

You get similar optimization as with [jpegtran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpegtran) (see answer by OutOfMemory) but jpegoptim can't save to progressive jpegs.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a command line tool called 'picopt' (similar to ImageOptim) that uses external programs to optimize JPEGs, PNGs, GIFS, animated GIFS and even comic book archive contents (CBR/CBZ).

This is suitable for use with homebrew on OS X or Linux systems where you have installed tools like jpegrescan, jpegtran, optipng, gifsicle, etc.

https://github.com/ajslater/picopt

Comment: Is there a windows version of this?

Comment: if you can install its posix dependencies in a windows environment like cygwin it might. You'd be the first to test it, though.

Answer (score 3):

I too would recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). It has a command line option to remove EXIF metadata

```
mogrify -strip image.jpg
```

There are plenty of other tools out there that do the same thing.

As far as recompressing JPEGs go, don't. JPEGs are lossy to start with, so any form of recompression is only going to hurt image quality. However, if you have losslessly encoded images, some encoders do a better job than others. I have noticed that JPEGs done with Photoshop consistently look better than when encoded with ImageMagick (despite the same file size) due to [complicated reasons](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13442). Furthermore (and this is relevant to you), I know that at least Photoshop can save JPEGs as *optimized* which means they drop compatibility with some stuff that you probably don't care about to save a couple of KB. Also, make sure you don't have any colour profiles embedded and you may be able to save another couple of KB.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought 90% quality is the same across all image tools. Is Photoshop the only tool that uses optimized DCT coefficients?

Comment: I though 90% was going to be the same across various tools until I tried saving the same images in Photoshop and Imagemagick. I found that about 70% in Save for Web in Photoshop made files that were about the same size as 92% in Imagemagick, but the Photoshop files were noticeably better quality. I have no idea how other tools do it.

Comment: Do you know how do perform the EXIF meta-data stripping using the PHP version of ImageMagick?

Comment: @Sonny Not really, but you might be interested in this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-stripimage.php

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I ended up finding.  Here's my thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540068

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using http://kraken.io It's ultra-fast webapp which will optimize your PNG and JPEG files far better than smush.it does.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use JpegOptim, it's free and really nice, you can specify the quality, the size you want ... And easy to use in command line.

[JpegOptim](http://freecode.com/projects/jpegoptim)

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend this for near-transparency:

```
convert 'yourfile.png' ppm:- | jpeg-recompress -t 97 -q veryhigh -a -m smallfry -s -r -S disable - yourfile.jpg
```

It uses [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s `convert` and `jpeg-recompress` from [jpeg-archive](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/jpeg-archive).

Both are open-source and work on Windows, Mac and Linux. You may want to tweak the options above for different quality expectations.