# JPG File Size Optimization - PHP, ImageMagick, & Google's Page Speed

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpeg, exif, pagespeed

I have photo gallery code that does image re-sizing and thumbnail creation.  I use ImageMagick to do this.  I ran a gallery page through Google's Page Speed tool and it revealed that the re-sized images and thumbnails both have about an extra 10KB of data (JPEG files specifically).

What can I add to my scripts to optimize the file size?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I am using the `imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS` filter with a blur setting of `0.9` when calling the `resizeImage()` function.  JPEGs have a quality setting of `80`.

Comment: What arguments are you giving ImageMagick?

Comment: Updated my question to address the settings/arguments.  My understanding is that Google's Page Speed removes 10KB of information in a lossless way, it doesn't further compress the image.  Is there meta-data I can strip out somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this SO question, "[Tools for JPEG optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985725/tools-for-jpeg-optimization)", that has some good information, but the solutions are outside of PHP.  Using hints from that question's solutions I found that there were two lossless optimizations that could be performed:

1. Optimization of the Huffman coding tables
2. Removal of meta-data (EXIF, etc)

Both of can be accomplished with `ImageMagick` this way:

1. According to [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php), the optimal Huffman coding tables are computed by default. This step is already taken care of, yay!
2. Removal of [meta-data](http://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/index.html) can be accomplished very simply by using the [stripImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-stripimage.php) method.

One image I tested was reduced by 12KB.  The 600x450 file went from 63.42KB to 51.42KB, and the 140x105 thumbnail went from 17.98KB to 5.98KB.

Answer (score 3):

Run your images through Yahoo's SmushIt service, where the images are converted to a PNG with an exact number of colors. No loss in quality, but a loss in weight :)

Comment: That's a slick tool. It doesn't look like they have it set up as a service unfortunately.