# How to reduce App (.apk) Size

Tags: android

Help!

When I install my app on the phone to test, **it is showing up to be a HUGE size, 11.35 MB**. It is a very simple app that lets user browse through fun-facts. The only reason I can think of is that there are 14 JPEG files in the drawables which serve as background images of the fun-facts. The average size of these is about 500 KB.

I'd like to trim the size of my app, so as not to use up the precious resources on the user's device. Other than just getting rid of the pictures, are there ways to optimize the size of apk file?

EDIT: The pictures are photos taken by me using the Android phone itself.

Comment: try to ONLY use PNG format images in your android applications!

Comment: binnyb, I tried to save the jpeg file in png format. The png file was much bigger. So not sure how using png will be better here.

Comment: This is a very old thread, I know, but it came up on my search and I wanted add this: When you first convert a .jpeg to a .png, the png will probably be much larger. But png's are very 'squishy' and easily compressed. Easy to use services like TinyPNG.com can dramatically reduce image size, especially if your image has large blocks of similar colors.

Comment: You can also try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154269/reduce-apk-size-android/49472760#49472760](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154269/reduce-apk-size-android/49472760#49472760)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would recommend that you compress the `.jpg` files as much as possible, this should greatly reduce the size of your `.apk` file. A tool such as [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) which is free should help you do this. It has great resizing options.

Comment: I would say *reduce* the JPEG size (i.e. JPEG quality) rather than *compress* them.  JPEGs aren't very squishy.

Comment: Good point, but depending on the level of compression in the images, there could be room for additional compression in addition to reducing the size.

Comment: Nate Bross, Christopher, thanks. I installed Paint.NET. (great tool!) Both reducing the quality while saving OR Resizing option, reduce the size while not significantly altering the picture. I'm not sure about the *compress* option, how to do that (I'm assuming you don't mean compress to a .7z or something). But this will work for me.

Comment: Most people see a "quality" setting in JPEG images, some correctly call this compression. It has to do with how much information you are willing to loose. When you reduce the "quality" you are simply letting the JPEG algorithm decide what pixels it can guess the color of. More guesses, smaller size.

Comment: @Tom Slick. OK, that makes sense. Good info. Thanks!

Comment: See [Tools for JPEG optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985725/tools-for-jpeg-optimization) for some other suggested tools.

Answer (score 36):

Other answers mention shrinking images. You might also consider trying [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to shrink your bytecode. [Here's an article](http://blog.javia.org/android-and-proguard-the-perfect-pair/) on applying ProGuard to an Android app.

Comment: Shrinking the bytecode would have a barely noticable effect on APK size, especially in comparison to cutting down the size of the 10MB+ of JPEGs.

Comment: @Christopher: other answers have already mentioned shrinking images, but nobody has mentioned shrinking code, so I'm giving the OP another tool to consider.

Comment: I see, but I guess nobody mentioned optimising using ProGuard because it would have virtually no benefit for an app like this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The code in this app is pretty small & straightforward, but I'll keep this in mind for future applications.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that your jpg's aren't stored in any higher resolution than necessary. A nice Android phone has a screen resolution of 1920x1200 or 2560x1440 (circa 2015)<strike>800 x 480</strike> , so your backgrounds shouldn't contain any more pixels than that (unless your app supports some kind of zooming). Also, are the backgrounds photographs? If not, you may find that using a vector based image format like svg, or one with a dynamic palette like gif, will reduce the file size even more.

Comment: *voteup* The backgrounds are photographs indeed. I did follow your advice while using the the tool another poster suggested & brought down the pixel sizes to about 800 X 480 . Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated the question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE**

With the introduction of Support Library 23.2, now you can replace many of your Image assets with SVG ( w/ or w/o animations) to reduce the apk size further.

**ORIGINAL**

This could be a late reply but might be helpful for future users.

Refer this [link](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/).
To summarise the page, it mentions below key points that will help reduce the apk size in totality:

- Use **ProGaurd**
- **Remove any debug info** you have in the app ( statements such as Log.i()). They can be wrapped in a condition which is only enabled while testing out the application.
- Use **recommended media formats**

  - Image: PNG orJPG
  - Audio: AAC
  - Video: H264 AVC
- **Compress images** using [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or [PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)
- Use [9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) to **scale images**
- **Find unused resources** using this [tool](https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/) and **remove them**.
- **Avoid using multiple resources** to achieve the same functionality. The resources do not only limit to images but extend to APIs. At times a singular API can provide multiple results instead of using two or three different APIs. Duplicated strings and assets are also a waste of space.

Answer (score 8):

### Convert to `WebP` which will significantly reduce the app size

***It reduced the app size of my app which was `40 mb` to `25 mb`***

**Steps:**

- Right click on `res`
- convert to `WebP`

---

**What it does**: It reduces the size to `png` to `WebP` format. Quality is also not destroyed

---

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Beyond optimizing images, I also found it useful to verify the Support Libraries you use. I have a relatively simple application targeting platforms with API >=10, still my APK ended up being 2.2M, or after using ProGuard, 1.4M. When I looked into the APK, the code was 1.5M and there were a lot of additional resources included (abc_*) I knew nothing about.

Then I found this: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Turns out I did not need appcompat-v7, only support-v4, and making this change to my dependencies reduced the APK size to 1.7M (0.9M with ProGuard).
Understandably, the Support Libraries carry a lot of extra (code and resource), so making sure you use only the ones you need might help.

(Even though -0.5M is not significant for a 11M app, I am posting this here because I kept ending up on this page while searching for a solution...)

Answer (score 4):

- Use [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) compress your project's png or
  jpg format image files, It can greatly reduce the size of the image
  without loss in image quality；
- Some images use tinypng compress may distortion, you can convert
  these images to webP format, use [智图](http://zhitu.tencent.com/) or 
  [iSparta](http://isparta.github.io/) can convert other format to webP;
- Use Lint check no use resources and delete it;

Answer (score 4):

Four Ways and your app size will become from 11.35 MB to near about 5 MB.
First, check the app components via App Analyzer (an inbuilt feature of Android studio), Simply click on Build on the top and click Analyze APK. It will show you everything what components apk is using.

1. Enable Proguard
2. Enable ShrinkResource
3. resConfigs (Name it, like if your app is in only one language eg English then simply specify resConfigs "en")
4. Convert all Images from .png or.jpg to webp (Most Important).

Steps to achieve these steps.

1 & 2. For Proguard and ShrinkResource

In gradle, simply add

```
               release {
                       minifyEnabled true
                       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                       shrinkResources true
                }
```

3. For resConfigs

   ```
       defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.goparties.gpuser"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 27
       resConfigs "en"
   ```

   }
4. TO convert all Images from .png or.jpg to webp

Very easy process: Just right click on the drawable folder(drawable,drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc) and click on convertToWebP (last option).

Min SDK version should be 18.

Here we go: Now analyze your app size.

Bingo !!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

One more thing to add on image file size - different algorithms can have a significant effect on the final size.  I found that Yahoo's www.smushit.com is a lot more effective (at least for .png) than compressors and codecs I have on my computer right now.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Unfortunately Yahoo shut down the hosting for Smushit with little notice.  There are a number of alternatives, such as https://kraken.io/web-interface, https://tinypng.com/, http://nitrosmush.com/.  I haven't done a comparison, but did see one site favoring TinyPNG over Kraken for final file size.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I can point out from experience.

1. If you use eclipse to create apk file then the resources are duplicated (atleast it happened in my case), you can try using ant and build.xml to create the apk and compare the size.
2. Also look into aliasing the resources. The link for it is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources).

Comment: Can you elaborate on resources being "duplicated"?

Comment: In my case I had unzipped my apk and found the contents of res folder (drawable, layout folders etc) in top level directory, AND the res folder containing all the assets, thus they were being packaged in twice. I thought that this must be something unique to my Eclipse workspace. And when I started doing commandline builds with Ant, it all worked out and the res folder was packaged in once. Thats the reason I asked you to look into it.

Comment: @omermuhammed: make sure you do not have assets folder or resource folder in project settings as the source folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think this [post](https://blog.getsigneasy.com/engineering/signeasy-android-app-lighter/) would give you a better idea on all the possible methods to use to reduce your apk size by a huge margin.

I will give you an excerpt of the same.

1. Use only the  required libraries from Google Play Services.
2. Apply ProGuard to your app.
3. Minify and shrink.
4. Adopt vector drawables.
5. Use the android lint.
6. Split your apk based on the architectures
7. Adding resConfigs in your gradle files to specify localization languages.

   > This strips away all other string files that could’ve been added by other libraries in languages you don’t even support.

Answer (score 2):

I know i am late here  to answer this question but i reduce my app size using below techniques so i want to share these things with all.

1)- Use WebP images instead of Jpeg  images, it will provide huge impact on apk size if you are using multiple images.

2)-Use VectorDrawables if you are using simple small icons in your app.

3)- Use View's tint property in xml to avoid multiple same icons but Different in color.

> search DrawableTint and TintableImageview

4)- Use 9-patch images and avoid duplication of image or anything in the app code.

Below are the links to refer to reduce APK size.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-split

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html

Answer (score 2):

WebP image format: provides lossy compression (like JPEG) as well as transparency (like PNG) but can provide better compression than either JPEG or PNG

[Convert images to WebP](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html#convert_images_to_webp)

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above most upvoted answers, I would like to answer with latest tools from Google's Android Studio.

Google recently has introduced the  [Android App Bundle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D63S4ZRBls)  in which playstore automatically delivered optimized version of apk to end devices.
Now developers just has to generate Signed Bundle, and upload to play store, dev job is done. Don't forget always use SVG images.

Also please have look into [Deliver Features On-Demand with Dynamic Features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=httqEshs_Bk&feature=youtu.be)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do for reduce build size by Images (Also can work for iOS)
Here I am sharing the great tool called “OPTIPNG ” (you can download from [here](http://goo.gl/FSNnI2) )which will help us to reduced the build specially by using Images, It will reduced the Image size for PNGs we are using without degrading quality (Resolution and color) of the image.

Example –  If your image size is off 698 KB then It will simpley  reduced size to 564 KB

Here is the execution steps for OPTIPNG 0.7.5

1)  Terminal -> CD /YourLocal path of OPTIPNG

2) type “./configure”

3) type  ”sudo make install”

Intallation should be done now

4) type ”  optipng /your image path

You will get result in byte and can also check your size

Answer (score 0):

You could also try http://www.webresizer.com/resizer/ Its an online tool, Did a pretty good job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Trimage image compressor](http://trimage.org/) for compressing images and reducing the size of apk.It has good compression rate,easy to use,retains the quality of image and is also available in Ubuntu.Beside this i enabled ProGuard and worked on Lint issues to reduce APK size.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the ways to reduce the app size. In detail is explained in the following link.

https://medium.com/@fahimsakri/put-your-apks-on-diet-cc3f40843c84#.m860q8s1u

Proguard

vector drawables

Apk splits

Optimize png images

Remove unused resources

9-patch images

Compress Jpeg images

Remove debug information

Avoid duplications

Use lint extensively

Reuse resource whenever possible

Recommended Media formats

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce apk size by del R.class and replaces the reference to constant.

See this: 
https://github.com/mogujie/ThinRPlugin

Answer (score 0):

APK contains a zip file of all the things that your mobile application has including Java class files, resource files among others.

One of the simple ways to make your APK smaller is to reduce the number and size of the resources it contains. In particular, you can remove resources that your app no longer uses, and you can use scalable Drawable objects in place of image files.

Answer (score 0):

Use MinifyEnable true 
and ShrinkResources true

MinifyEnabled will reduce your code as it compresses it.
While shrinkResources shrink the resources.

To use ShrinkResources you have to set minifyEnbled true.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few techniques:

1. Proguard
2. Unnecessary Resources
3. Webp images
4. Signed apk
5. Android App Bundle

For detailed explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63988744/13928327

Answer (score -1):

use SVG images instead of jpg in order to reduce the apk size.
put your image files in the database .. so that the users of your app can download it from the database and it will reduce the app size dramatically..