# Tips to reduce app installed size using eclipse?

Tags: java, android

I just built my first android app. A scientific calculator. Once installed I thought of checking it's size and comparing it with similar apps. My app is 650kb, the most popular currently on the play store is 500kb and the default one is 4kb.

My app has only one activity, with a class and layout which before compiling are 20kb together. So how can my app be taking 100kb more than the most popular one? I'm just curious, I suppose there are files generated authomatically that can be eliminated to save space (like some images I found inside /res) but cannot just delete files randomly.

What can I do to make the app lighter? How can I check which files are unused?

Comment: You can refer [here....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815269/how-to-reduce-app-apk-size)

Comment: you could not care.... storage size is of no consequence to most users.

Comment: 20 BYTES??? Surely you mean kilobytes ...

Comment: yes, 20 I corrected it. 20KB I mean!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to delete unused image and use image optimize tools to decrease size of png (e.g. ImageOptim). Normally user doesn't care about the app size, you can also offer to sdcard option if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by GobyGoby, deleting unused images and compressing used images will definitely lower the size of your app. You could also run your application through something like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used it myself, but it seems to be the most popular tool.