# Android - Is it possible to upgrade to an larger size app from an smaller size app?

Tags: android

I have an app that is 8mb in size. For some reason it needs to be only 3mb. So I came up with the idea to build a small app initially that when opened(or button is clicked within), it downloads the offical app of 8mb and uninstalls the initial app.

Please advice me on this ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce App (.apk) Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815269/how-to-reduce-app-apk-size)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, the way you wish - if something like this was possible it would open the device to security threats that can install malware using a credible app.
You will still have to download an 8mb app and the user needs to confirm he wants to install it, so it's the same as downloading it initially.

What you can do is remove all resources like images, sounds and text from the app, then on the first start you can download them from your server and cache them on the device. This way you lower the app size to only the necessary base code(controllers and models) and download all the presentation data later, to show it to the user.

Comment: First of all thank you Milen. But lets say what if I want the user to click a link/button on my dummy(Smaller) app and then it downloads the 8MB app??

Comment: To install an application, after the user have clicked the button, you need to redirect him to an .apk file for your application or download the .apk file to the memory where you can invoke it. Either way it will prompt the user that this is a third party application ,that may be harmful to his device, and will ask for permission to install it. You may want to read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing audio and video files in app then you can make them download at installation time, This is the only way I guess

Comment: Thank user...  but now how do I achieve this ??

Comment: Following way can be used to reduce the apk size : 

When we place the app on app store there go to advanced option. there you can add your videos and audios. When the user install the app from app store then these video and audio files can be downloaded

see this link 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html