# Flutter app size is huge

Tags: android, flutter

I am an Android app Developer using java, and I have come to know about Flutter using dart language created by Google. I found it quite intresting and because it builds the app for both Android and ios. I have created a simple TabsLayout Application for Android, the size of the Application 27MB, please have a look at the screenshot of the simple TabLayout Flutter App.

[image] I have two questions thats listed below

1. I have seen that the Flutter app has size of more than 25 MB, so why the Flutter app is taking huge size after developing?
2. How to reduce the size of Flutter app ?

Comment: ad 1) simply use `Analyze apk` in your android studio to see what is the content of your apk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce App (.apk) Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815269/how-to-reduce-app-apk-size)

Comment: @GoldwynDator flutter apps are not created by using AS?

Comment: Flutter minimum size is more than 5MB of APK file. Maybe your App is in build for debugging, so the final APK is bigger than the one build for Release. However I think you're talking about its size when it is installed and not the APK itselfs. Installed Apps takes about the double of original APK size.

Comment: @GoldwynDator maybe 30 years ago someone was using a dumb text editor (without any context help, suggestions etc), nowadays  i cannot imagine it, and memory is cheap, your time not

Comment: @GoldwynDator that is the most unjustified statement I have read today. It's like saying "you should always travel by bike, because cars use gas"

Comment: @TimCastelijns `"you should always travel by bike, because cars use gas"` the funny thing is that Dutchman said that ;-)

Comment: @emandt I have released the apk just for testing that how much size it creates and still the apk size is 7.52 and app size is 27MB

Comment: @pskink unintentional :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `debug` app will be larger in size , but your `release` app should be smaller in size approximately 7-8 MB . Minimum size of app itself is 4.7Mb see [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833#issuecomment-410103493) , It is still larger compared to native app but cannot expect any thing better from cross platform

Check this [documentation](https://flutter.io/faq/#how-big-is-the-flutter-engine)

**Edit:-**
The minimum size is now down to [4.06 MB](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833#issuecomment-447151309)

Comment: it's no less than that,now it's just 4.7MB [see](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833#issuecomment-410103493)

Comment: @RaoufRahiche , that is the minimum size and I was telling about his app size any way thanks for the link, I will update my answer

Comment: @so how can I reduce the size of the app

Comment: The point is you cannot reduce more than 6-8mb  for your app in release mode . you can never get an app with size 3-4 mb using flutter

Comment: @Redman could you please see my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761934/apk-size-v-s-installed-app-size

Answer (score 3):

As of today

**In Android**

the download size of a [minimal Flutter app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/75228a59dacc24f617272f7759677e242bbf74ec/examples/hello_world) (no Material Components, just a single Center widget, built with `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`), bundled and compressed as a release APK, to be approximately 4.3 MB for ARM, and 4.6 MB for ARM 64.

`flutter build apk`
(defaults to --release) builds a single apk to support the target devices might result in a very large apk (fat apk)
One way to reduce the size of your apk is to create multiple apks that contain file for specific screen densities or abis.

Run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

this command builds two apks's
targeting arm,arm64 based devices
the apk's are located at `build/app/outputs`

**On iOS,**

a release IPA of the same app has a download size of 10.9 MB on an iPhone X, as reported by Apple’s App Store Connect. The IPA is larger than the APK mainly because Apple encrypts binaries within the IPA, making the compression less efficient.

by default, we build universal binaries for iOS that include both armv7 and arm64 architectures for all three of:

- Flutter.framework (the engine)
- App.framework (the AOT-compiled app)
- Runner (the entrypoint of the app)

Apple does app-thinning on their end such that the end-user downloads only the bits relevant to their device. To get the download size,

1. log in to App Store Connect,
2. select your app, navigate to the Activity page,
3. select your build,
4. then click the App Store File Sizes link.

sources:

1. [flutter FAQ](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#how-big-is-the-flutter-engine)
2. [Reduce --release apk and ipa sizes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833)