# Flutter app size is much bigger than what Play Console says it will be

Tags: flutter, android-app-bundle

Building my app using the appbundle mode gave me this:

> flutter build appbundle
>
> Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab (16.0MB).

When uploaded to the Play Console, it says the app size will be between 9,08 and 9,43 MB. But, on Play Store, when downloading to my device, it is 22 MB.

Building the apks, I've got this:

> flutter build apk --split-per-abi
>
> Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (9.5MB).
> Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (9.8MB).

PS: my app is in beta release on Play Store. Could this be related to the size increase?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (2 weeks ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

Answer (score 1):

The apk size generated [between 9,08 and 9,43 MB] it's like a .rar or .zip file . it's compressed. and when it is uncompressed [installed], the size is bigger.

The difference in size can be because you have unoptimized images / videos / fonts , etc in your app.

However. 22 mb is a good apk size. The installed size is around 20 mb , [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761934/apk-size-v-s-installed-app-size) of August 2018 a simple installed app is 27mb , so flutter has already lowered the installed size. But there will be a final point.

Considering that the app you build can be installed in IOS, Android, Windows, and in the future Fuchsia , it's a sacrifice that the developer makes.

Flutter already optimized the space in [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833).

I would suggest

- Avoid using images
- Avoid at all costs using video/gif
- Avoid unnecesary libraries
- Optimize the fonts you are using [create a custom one ]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My app uses just a few images, no video/gif and external fonts at all. The apk size and the size in the Play Store for download used to be both around 8 MB in the last version. From that version to this new one, I added 3 new plugins (cloud_firestore, firebase_analytics and firebase_core) and changed the build process to use the appbundle.

Comment: Oh . Firebase will add a lot of size to the app because it's using native libraries wich you don't see but the blugin requires for it to work. Per example , the cloud_firestore package is using 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.1.0' , 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0' and 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0' under the hood , using more space.