# JPEG Optimization from PHP running on hosted accounts

Tags: php, optimization, jpeg

I am looking for a loss-less JPEG optimization tool that I can include in a PHP-based photo gallery software.

I already checked the following question, but ruled out the tools mentioned there for reasons I'll explain below:

[Tools for JPEG optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985725/tools-for-jpeg-optimization)

The command line tools jpegtran and jpegoptim are not available in the average PHP hosting account. The web-based tools (www.smush.it, www.kraken.io) all have a limit of 1 MB for processed images.

The 1 MB limit is a problem, because the gallery software delivers images based on browser-size and I also want to support Full HD and even larger displays. Depending on content, photos prepared for such resolutions can get larger than 1 MB.

Any hints on a solution are appreciated!

Comment: buy vps, create image optimization there, create api, include api connection in software

Comment: Dagon, right, that is feasible, but I was hoping there might be an easier/more inexpensive solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found my answer in another stack overflow question:

[JPG File Size Optimization - PHP, ImageMagick, & Google's Page Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540068/jpg-file-size-optimization-php-imagemagick-googles-page-speed)

ImageMagick already does the Huffman optimization. I assumed it doesn't because my ImageMagick files were still larger then the ones from jpegtran & Co. However, that was only because I did not strip the metadata.

Cheers, Robert

Answer (score 0):

There are no solution.

Either use some command-line utility or increase memory limit.

(and, to let you know, it's not target image *file size* but uploaded image *dimensions* that puts you into trouble with memory limit.

Comment: The websites smush.it and kraken.io limit by file size not dimensions. The limit is 1 MB. That has nothing to do with the PHP memory limit for file uploads. I can upload files > 1 MB via my gallery software, but I cannot have smush.it or kraken.io optimize these files.

Comment: dunno what sites you're talking about but memory limit being affected by image dimensions, not file size

Comment: The sites are www.smush.it and www.kraken.io. Smush.it can also be called from PHP via an HTTP URL, but again, they support only files up to 1 MB, while I would also like to process larger files. Again, this has nothing to do with any upload memory limit of PHP.